# Line 1 of txt files being ignored by delphi app, why?

Tags: text

I have a delphi prog that reads from thousands of .txt script files that I have created over some years. I had to do some mass changes so used a search and replace program which in itself took a good few hours! The problem is now the top line of all the txt files seems to be messed up somehow - to me it looks fine however the delphi program doesn't read it and TortoiseSVN records it as a changed line!!

What on earth has happened and how might I resolve it? So far I'm having to delete all the files and remake them. Deleting the line and rewriting doesn't work - even Crtl+A and pasting the old file contents doesn't work! Its as if the header is corrupt?

Comment: You could use a text editor like Notepad++ to view any hidden characters before you perform the search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a problem with end lines? (windows/UNIX/Mac are different eg  \n or \n\r ) use an editor able to show special characters. I think you can with tortoise diff, switching the right option. Else, try with notepad++, for example

Comment: notepad++ isnt showing anything but I just tried a hex editor and instead of starting right away with the text it begins with EF BB BF >_<

Comment: Just google it. EF BB BF start file. Its some utf 8 thing. change coding.

Comment: New to me.. will do. Thanks!

Comment: check [this:](http://blog.fourthwoods.com/2011/07/11/removing-the-byte-order-mark-inserted-in-source-files-by-visual-studio/)